# javascript __doPostBack causing previous line not to be called?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pokein

I am using PokeIn and when I run the following call:

```
function OnSucceeded(messagefixed) {
            if (PokeIn.IsConnected) {
               pCall['Dummy'].SendMessageToAllUsers(messagefixed);

               __doPostBack('LinkButton1', messagefixed);
           }
           else
               alert("This client is not connected!");
       }
```

It doesn't work... it just does a post back, however, if I comment out the __doPostBack it works perfectly fine and does the previous call.. am i doing something wrong?

The "SendMessageToAllUsers" is a function from the code-behind in VB.NET which is:

```
Public Sub SendMessageToAllUsers(ByVal stMessage As String)
    CometWorker.Groups.Send("SSID:" & iSDID, ("UpdateTime('" & stMessage & "');"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `SendMessageToAllUsers` *synchronous* (it waits for the message to be sent before returning) or *asynchronous* (it starts sending the message but may return before the message has been sent)? If the latter, __doPostBack may interrupt the sending of the message.

Comment: I guess it is synchronous? I dont know how to check, but if that's the case.. is there a command to make it wait until its processed fully? or run in the background so we can do the post back?

Comment: I suspect `SendMessageToAllUsers` is asynchronous. You would have to consult the PokeIn documentation and see how you could determine when the message has been sent.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything on their end, what are my options now?